# Vary Alignment for Posts on a Blog

Tags: html, css, blogs

This has probably a name and I just can't come up with it. I spent the last 30 minutes quenching out Google, but to no avail. Sorry for the bad title too. I really don't know what to call this.

I want to make it (on Tumblr, if that helps?) that for example the first post is left aligned, the second post is right aligned and the third post left aligned again.. and so on.

I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: :nth-of-type(even) and :nth-of-type(odd) CSS selectors: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp or :nth-child(odd): http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, really!